# How to strip leading or trailing spaces, <br>, empty <div>, empty <p> or alike in Python easily?

Tags: python, html-parsing, strip

I have paragraphs input from users. However, there are always leading or trailing `<br>`, empty `<p>`, or empty `<div>` which are meaningless at all, and they affect the formatting of the output. How do I strip them in Python nicely and correctly?

An example of a user input is as below:

```
<br><div></div>
<div>Hello <a href="world.html">World!</a>.</div>
<br><br>
<div>Image below:<br>
<img src="abc.jpg" /><br><br></div><p></p>
```

And the ideal result that I want is:

```
<div>Hello <a href="world.html">World!</a>.</div>
<br /><br />
<div>Image below:<br />
<img src="abc.jpg" /></div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: This might be a job for [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) or possibly regular expressions if you only have a few lines to process.

Comment: Thanks Levon. I will check out BeautifulSoup. Wish that somebody has done it before, as I think this should be a very routine html data cleaning process.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly this time around you could try removing empty tags - that is, tags which have no text:

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as bs
>>> tags = bs('<div></div><p></p><div>Test text.</div><p></p>').findAll()
>>> [ tag for tag in tags if tag.text ]
[<div>Test text.</div>]
```

Comment: Thank you Eduardo Ivanec, Sometimes the user has several paragraphs. Also, there are `<a>` links and other tags, which I want to preserve. I only want to strip leading and trailing meaningless tags. I will check out BeautifulSoup and see how it can work.

Comment: Hi hllau. I misunderstood your question of course, please see the edited version of my answer in case it's useful now.

Comment: I have updated the question a bit for a good example.
Thanks for improving the answer, but it still does not solve the problem when there are images and line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
get_text('', '<br/>')
```

I have the same problem of breaking text into multiple lines by the tag

```
'<br/>'
```

This function could at least join the lines into a single line, which could remove the effect of this tag. Hope that works!